# Method to Display Cell Again in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Which method should I use in order to display a cell again in a `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

If your data has been updated you can refresh the view by sending the reloadData message to your tableView:

`[myTableView reloadData];`

Apple's [UITableView reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload specific cells, use [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) method. For example, if you want to reload the cell at row 20 in section 0 and the cell at row 4 in section 2 without an animation:

```
[cell reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:20 inSection:0],
                               [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:2],
                               nil]
            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

If you want to reload *all* the cells in the table view, then use [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`reloadData`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) method (but be aware of the performance implications):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Alternatively, if you just want to redraw a cell (rather than reloading it in order to update its information), you can use [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)'s [`setNeedsDisplay`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) method:

```
[[cell view] setNeedsDisplay];
```